# Plotly does not show properly the figure title in google collaboratory notebook

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I am using plotly in colab but i tried a lot to let it show the title properly.

```py
scatt_plot = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Total Income'],
                      mode='lines',
                      line=dict(color='rgb(200, 50, 50)', width=1.5),
                      text= "Income",
                      hoverinfo="text + x + y",
                      connectgaps=True,
                      name = "Income",
                      textfont=dict(family='Arial', size=12))

layout = go.Layout(title = "Income in 3 years")

fig = go.Figure(data=[scatt_plot], layout= layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

The title of figure in this case should be "Income in 3 years" but it generates [object object] as figure title. This snippet of code works well in local jupyter but the problem appears only with colab.

I used this snippet of code to browse plotly plots in colab.

```py
import IPython

def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))

IPython.get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', configure_plotly_browser_state)
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
```